# Unable to extract fuel prices from updated website

Tags: php, parsing

I used to use a website from the RAC to gather todays fuel prices, but they've changed the format and now it's all javascripted. Anyone fancy having a look and see if they can extract just the price of diesel in a usable format?  Here's the website.

https://datawrapper.dwcdn.net/oDTQ2/48/

Ideally something in php as the rest of my coding is already using that.

Massive thanks

Comment: What do you mean with "it's all javascripted"? In the end that page is just displaying a html table.

Comment: @OHG I assume they mean it's a dynamic web page and the table isn't rendered immediately

Comment: In the old page you could load the page with php, parse through it and read the values, now this ones page source doesn't have any of the actual data available to parse.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the end the data seem to come from:

https://static.dwcdn.net/data/oDTQ2.csv?v=1646751660000

The trick the is to discover what the number behind the `v` parameter stands for. This is a time, in milliseconds, since the Unix Epoch (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT). In this case it is "2022-03-08 07:01:00.000". I think you need to update that number to get the correct prices.

Oh, I simply used the [developer tools of my browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) to check what was downloaded for this page. And saw one file with this response:

```
Unleaded,Super unleaded,Diesel,LPG
156.37,167.75,162.28,80.08
pence per litre,pence per litre,pence per litre,pence per litre
↗ Likely to rise,↗ Likely to rise,↗ Likely to rise,
7 March 2022,,,
```